# Python does not import list in dns.resolver

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dnspython

I am writing a code which will resolve CNAME from the list of domains but my current script only resolve the first line of the `list.txt` and skips the rest.

I check `"dl"` import all the lines into list by running `print(dl)` but dns.resolver is not running check on each list data.

My sample Code is:

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import dns.resolver

d = open("list.txt" , "r")
dl = d.read().splitlines()

try:
    for dom in dl:
        answer = dns.resolver.resolve(dom, 'CNAME')
        for rdata in answer:
            print("CNAME", ':', rdata.to_text())
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

`list.txt` is:

```
www.google.com
www.github.com
www.facebook.com
```

Desired output is:

```
CNAME : www.gcaname.com
CNAME : www.gcaname.com
The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: www.github.com. IN CNAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
for dom in dl:
        try:    
            answer = dns.resolver.resolve(dom, 'CNAME')
            for rdata in answer:
                print("CNAME of %s" % dom, ':', rdata.to_text())
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

Comment: this technique makes dns resolution optional and all dns errors are silently swallowed. Please ponder the zen of python to improve this answer...

`>>> import this`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
answers = dns.resolver.query('mail.google.com', 'CNAME')
print ' query qname:', answers.qname, ' num ans.', len(answers)
for rdata in answers:
    print ' cname target address:', rdata.target
```

Comment: I want to import the list of URL. providing mail.google.com will only look for single domain